# Решил попробовать воссоздать бильярдный тренажер, с чего начать? На чем писать?

Tags: проект

Работаю в бильярдном клубе, на днях осенило, создать тренажер, который в реальном времени будет проецировать на бильярдный стол траекторию шара. Думал, что такого еще не существует, но погуглив нашёл как раз то что нужно, вот только кроме 47 секунд на ютубе и кучи дубликатов этого же видоса на других ресурсах без ссылок на источник или какую-то информацию - ничего. Поэтому решил попробовать сделать сам. Программированием только начал интересоваться, но очень хочу что бы это был мой первый мини-проект. 
Хочу сделать его сам и с нуля. Подскажите с чего начать, какой язык выбрать, может быть разобрать какой-то пример? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VmS6dDGz7Ng

Comment: Это непростая задача для начинающего: вам нужен будет высокопроизводительный алгоритм распознавания изображений, и физический эмулятор (как PhysX) - это в качестве библиотек нужно будет найти для любого прикладного языка, скорее всего `Java`, или `C#` . Можно писать всё самому конечно, но это много лишнего времени и много опыта потребуется.

Comment: С распознаванием изображения я так и думал, что нужны навороты, но что если начать с хотя бы виртуального построения (как в флэш играх-бильярдных) без привязки к реальному столу (для меня это будет уже неплохо), потом усложнить добавив привязку к трекерам на шарах/кие, будь то просто контрастными как в приложениях с AR или трекерами для захвата наподобие тех, которые на актеров надевают для наложения впоследствии графики?

Comment: можете начать конечно с без распознавания. Но это тут графика самая простая задача - рекомендую на C# написать, связь с камерой и проектором будет более глубокая, без разрешений. На C# для виртуальной версии можно будет подключить графическую библиотеку unity3d . Или можно даже написать приложение, как web-страницу (на JavaScript) - будет проще всего: получить доступ к вебкамере можно(после разрешения открывшего веб-страницу), проектор - это тот-же монитор. Вариантов много - выбирайте что вам больше интересно. Только такие обсуждения на SO Не приветствуются - приветствуются конкретные вопросы.

Comment: Наверное действительно начну с  web-страницы, т.к. в этом хоть малейшие познания имею. Большое спасибо за ответы, по поводу конкретики замечание учёл, просто не знал куда еще обратиться.